# WriteHTML in mfpdf displays squares

Tags: php, codeigniter, mpdf

Im using mpdf in codeigniter and the output display squares instead of korean language.

here is my code in writeHTML

```
$mpdf = new Mpdf\Mpdf('zh-aCJK');

$mpdf->WriteHTML('<div style="line-height:140%;font-size:12px;margin-top:15px;margin-bottom:35px;"><span style="color:#666666;font-family:/*Some korean font*/;font-size:12px;background-color:#ffffff;">세계를 </span><span class="ex" style="color:#DC143C;font-family:/*Some korean font*/;font-size:28px;background-color:#ffffff;">에 대하여</span><span style="color:#666666;font-family:/*Some korean font*/;font-size:28px;background-color:#ffffff;"> 너와 나, </span></div>');
```

the output is

[image]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Maybe try this: https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-variables/charset-in.html

Comment: I think it should work if you pass ['mode' => 'utf-8'] to constructor

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor parameter is wrong, mPDF accepts an array. Set up your development environment to be "warned" about it with a Notice.

None of your specified fonts are included in mPDF distribution and therefore will not display unless you set them up correctly. Default replacement is DejavuSans which does not support korean as far as I can tell.

With multiple languages across a document, use

```
$mpdf = new Mpdf\Mpdf(['autoLangToFont' => true]);

$mpdf->WriteHTML('<div style="line-height:140%;font-size:12px;margin-top:15px;margin-bottom:35px;">
    <span lang="zh">세계를 </span>
    <span lang="ko">에 대하여</span>,
    <span lang="ko"> 너와 나, </span>
</div>');

$mpdf->Output('example000.pdf', 'F');
```

(styles cleaned up.) This will select appropriate font families for given languages. Please note that I am just estimating language codes - I have little knowledge about CJK writing. In case all of your text is in korean, the `zh-aCJK` mode does not make sense in the first place.

If you want a custom font with a CJK support, follow the extensive documentation for custom fonts.

https://mpdf.github.io/fonts-languages/fonts-in-mpdf-7-x.html

Read more about overall configuration, including non-latin scripts at

https://mpdf.github.io/fonts-languages/choosing-a-configuration-v7-x.html